# Physical Remote that connects with pc?

Tags: pc, remote-control

I am looking for a physical remote so that I can press physical buttons that will

- be registered by my pc as if a certain keyboard button was pressed
- has multiple buttons, where I can choose which keyboard buttons they emulate
- Preferably bluetooth so that it is easy, and doesn’t require any extra receiver hardware

  does something like this exist?

Comment: Is this a remote for browser-based playback on a pc/mac? or another device? what potential inputs are you looking for (bluetooth, RF, wifi, capacitive material on  the end of a pointy stick)?

Comment: @JaredT I’ve significantly changed my question.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an "HTPC" (home theater PC) remote, there are many and plenty of them are programmable / have bluetooth / assortment of other features.

If you update your post with a budget and some more specific features you want, or with a few options that you want advice on choosing between, I'll be happy to help you narrow down a few specific choices.